# How to take video file from library in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to do this .I know it very simple question  .
Take Video: Take Picture: Choose from Library: Everything I find has separate buttons. Kinda like in the facebook app when you click on the camera button you get this picture.

I think people will me as soon as possible 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To take Picture, video and select an image from photo library, UIImagePickerController will help you.

Ref: [UIImagePickerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html)

To take picture and video, UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureMode has to be set properly.

Also the sourceType needs to be set as we required. See  UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.

I guess these summary will help you. See the reference for more details.

If u want to browse thru ur photo library,

```
    UIImagePickerController* picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
```

If u want to take new photo,

```
    UIImagePickerController* picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker. cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
```

If u want to take new video,

```
    UIImagePickerController* picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker. cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
```

Comment: If u want to browse through photolibrary,          UIImagePickerController* picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.allowsEditing = YES;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
        [picker release];

Comment: IS that it's also record the sound WIth VIdeo

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe this wasn't wrapped up in a little class. So I made one

https://github.com/fulldecent/FDTake

Example there shows taking a picture and choosing a photo from library.